# Copy draw.io diagram into Google Docs file

Tags: google-drive, app.diagrams.net

Is it possible to copy a drawing created with draw.io app (integrated with Drive) into a Google Doc?

I managed to export the draw.io file as .png and then paste it inside the Google Doc but it would be nice to be able to paste it (as an image or Rich Text) without the need to store the file in my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can now use the draw.io Google Docs addon to directly embed a draw.io diagram within a Google Doc. [This is the listing for the addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drawio-diagrams/clpbjldiohnnmfmkngmaohehlnfkmoea), but it's easier to open a Google Doc, select "add-ons", then "get add-ons" from the menu:

[image: The add-ons menu option in a Google Doc with the Get add-ons option selected]

A panel of add-ons will then display. In the search box type "draw.io" and click "install" to add the draw.io plugin.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I just needed that info :)

Comment: Has there been any progress on this matter since June? And do I take the response to mean that it'll just be a static image available i.e. there's no plan for 'live linking'? Thanks